# Error: /JavaServerFaces/default.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource

Tags: spring, maven, jsf, jetty

I'm begining with jsf-spring integration. I learn by downloading a jsf-spring integaration example from this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example/) and try to run. when i browser `http://http://localhost:8080/JavaServerFaces/default.xhtml`  then occur above error. I really don't understand why ???. I adjust to add plugin of jetty in `pom.xml`. Please let me know.

Here is added part in `pom.xml`

```
<build>
        <finalName>JavaServerFaces</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                <argLine>-Xmx2524m</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.3.0.M1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArgs>-Xmx1048m -Xms536m
                        -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</jvmArgs>
                    <reload>manual</reload>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>lib</name>
                            <value>${basedir}/target/spring-mvc/WEB-INF/lib</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>3</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                            <port>8080</port>
                            <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                        </connector>
                    </connectors>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</webAppSourceDirectory>
                    <webXml>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <classesDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</classesDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Here file web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

  <display-name>JavaServerFaces</display-name>

  <!-- Add Support for Spring -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <!-- Change to "Production" when you are ready to deploy -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Welcome page -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>default.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <!-- JSF Mapping -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Share your web.xml file

Comment: @SubodhJoshi, I have added web.xml file on my post

Comment: Did u tried with extension of *.jsf ?

Comment: That shouldn't make difference. Exception suggests either Maven build or Jetty configuration is done wrong. Either Maven didn't correctly put XHTML files in WAR file, or Jetty isn't configured to include the XHTML files from WAR in deployment. This is not a JSF problem.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC for clear the issue

Comment: @BalusC, you can please let me know how configure Jetty to include the XHTML

Comment: Sorry, I don't do Jetty. I'm just translating the cause of the problem in layman's terms so you can investigate further using new clues/keywords.

Comment: @BalusC, Thanks some your suggestion  :))) .

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my problem. i have to browser `http://localhost:8080/default.xhtml` instead `http://localhost:8080/JavaServerFaces/default.xhtml`. Because in plugin of jetty, i have configured `context path` is `/` not `/JavaServerFaces`. Thank @BalusC more :)